# Objective C Segues, dissolve programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, segue

I have two classes, machineClass and buttonsClass... From buttons class, I want a button to programmatically push into the machineClass.

Ive gotten that to work with:

```
machineClass *mc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"machineClass"];
mc.passedString = purchase;

[self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

*However*, this uses the default segue animation (where the view comes up vertically), and I think my app would look so much nicer if I used the **cross dissolve** transition instead.

Can anyone help? The best solution I've come up with is to change it to:

```
 [self presentViewController:mc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

But I don't like this as much...

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the target view controller's modal transition style in the storyboard. Or in code:

```
machineClass *mc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"machineClass"];
mc.passedString = purchase;
mc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

[self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:nil];
```