# fading in a new modal UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, fadein, modalviewcontroller

I was wondering how I would be able to push this button that takes me to a modal view controller and have that view controller fade in after i pushed the button instead of making it slide up which is the default way

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: This thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866682/objective-c-segues-dissolve-programmatically and this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867447/create-and-present-modal-view-controller-programatically may be helpful for you

Comment: You can also do this in the storyboard with a modal segue. If you inspect the segue, you can change the "transition" to "cross dissolve".

Comment: i looked at both of the links but im not sure where in my code to put the code, should i put in the view controller thats pushing the button to get to the other view controller, or in the one that i want to fade in, and how would i inspect the segue?

Comment: I found out how to inspect the segue and changed the transition style to "cross dissolve" but it still doesnt seem to work

Comment: What do you mean it "doesn't seem to work"? It either works or it doesn't. Be specific. What result did you get? If changing the transition to cross dissolve didn't work, you must have something setup wrong, or you not looking at the segue that you changed.

Comment: yeah it didnt work and i made sure the segue was the right one, idk what else could be set up wrong

Comment: Any updates on this? For me, my issue with "cross dissolve" is that it fades to black in between the two view controllers. Ideally I'd like a modal segue that simply fades from one view controller to the other.